# Why do I always get the defaut value in reducer in react instead of current value?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a reducer like this:

```
import { SHOWSNACKBARACTION } from '../actions';

export default function showSnackbar(state = false, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SHOWSNACKBARACTION:
      const showSnackbar = action.bool;
      return showSnackbar;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Every time an action is called, maybe another action, all reducer are called. So, if the action is not SHOWSNACKBARACTION, the showSnackbar reducer will return the default value = false.

But sometimes I want to return the current value, and don't want to change the value, if another action was called.

Is it possible, to return the current value, so nothing changes, or do I have to call the SHOWSNACKBARACTION everytime I call another action, so I don't get the default value?

I read, that I mustn't mutate the state in reducers. But do I have to update the state here or what can I do?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think your problem is where you are combining these reducers as this looks totally correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you said:

> if the action is not SHOWSNACKBARACTION, the showSnackbar reducer
>   will return the default value = false

This is not actually correct.

Redux will populate the parameter `state` with the current state. The default value is only used if the state is undefined. ie. when you first create the redux state.

Your current setup should work absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Combining my reducers looks like this:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import test from './test';
import metadata from './getMetaData';
import question from './getQuestion';
import showQuestion from './showQuestion';
import correct_answer from './sentGetAnswer';
import force_user_message from './force_user_message';
import showSnackbar from './showSnackbar';


const Reducer = combineReducers({
           test,
           metadata,
           question,
           showQuestion,
           correct_answer,
           force_user_message,
           showSnackbar
});

export default Reducer;
```

I think this is correct too, isnt it?

Maybe there is something broken on another part of the code. I gave all my reducers a console log wheater it has matched or not. When i set the SHOWSNACKBARACTION to true there comes this:

getMetaData.js:10 metadatareducer nicht ausgeführt

getQuestion.js:15 question nicht ausgeführt

showQuestion.js:10 showQustion nicht ausgeführt

sentGetAnswer.js:10 correct answer nicht ausgeführt

force_user_message.js:9 force_user_message reducer ausgeführt

showSnackbar.js:11 showSnackbar nicht ausgeführt

Application.js:156 metadata in Application sind da

getMetaData.js:10 metadatareducer nicht ausgeführt

getQuestion.js:15 question nicht ausgeführt

showQuestion.js:10 showQustion nicht ausgeführt

sentGetAnswer.js:10 correct answer nicht ausgeführt

force_user_message.js:16 forced_user_message_default

showSnackbar.js:7 showSnackbar reducer ausgeführt

showSnackbar.js:8 true

Application.js:156 metadata in Application sind da

Application.js:76 welcome gerendert

getMetaData.js:10 metadatareducer nicht ausgeführt

getQuestion.js:15 question nicht ausgeführt

showQuestion.js:10 showQustion nicht ausgeführt

sentGetAnswer.js:10 correct answer nicht ausgeführt

force_user_message.js:16 forced_user_message_default

showSnackbar.js:7 showSnackbar reducer ausgeführt

showSnackbar.js:8 true

Application.js:76 welcome gerendert

index.js:131 der request zum forcen geht ######################

getMetaData.js:7 metadatareducer ausgeführt

getQuestion.js:15 question nicht ausgeführt

showQuestion.js:10 showQustion nicht ausgeführt

sentGetAnswer.js:10 correct answer nicht ausgeführt

force_user_message.js:16 forced_user_message_default

showSnackbar.js:11 showSnackbar nicht ausgeführt

Application.js:156 metadata in Application sind da

getMetaData.js:10 metadatareducer nicht ausgeführt

getQuestion.js:15 question nicht ausgeführt

showQuestion.js:10 showQustion nicht ausgeführt

sentGetAnswer.js:10 correct answer nicht ausgeführt

force_user_message.js:16 forced_user_message_default

showSnackbar.js:7 showSnackbar reducer ausgeführt

showSnackbar.js:8 true

Application.js:76 welcome gerendert

You can see, last time showSnackbar is set to true. But in react developer tools i can see it is false. How is that possible?

EDIT:

it looks like the developer tools dont show me the correct values. Do you know this issue? Or is it possible to refresh them?

EDIT 2:

Ok, I found out, that in react developer tools in firefox all works fine. In Chrome it seems to be broken.